# Solving basic Trigonometry equations on a Ti-84 Plus

Tags: trigonometry, calculator

I am trying to solve some equations for example: tanθ = 2/4 or tan15 = x/30 but I do not know how I would use a Calculator to solve these as I do not know how to format them or which symbols to use for θ and x, thanks.

Comment: This is probably not the site for this. You should consult the manual or google. Anyway, there should be a function $\tan^{-1}$ (possibly above the  $\tan$ button). Then to solve for $\theta$, punch in $\tan^{-1}(2/4)$. For the second one, punch in $30*\tan(15)$. You aren't literally going to put in $\tan \theta = 2/4$ in the calculator screen because it is a calculator not a _solver_. **You** do the solving.

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TI-84 Plus cannot symbolically solve any equation, but there are two other options to solve equations:

1. Algebraically on paper, and then use the calculator to get a decimal estimate.
2. Graph both sides of your equation, and determine the intersection point(s). This will result in the solutions as well.